# Windows Defender, Bluetooth and Sticky Notes, all stopped working overnight. Plus blue screens

Tags: windows-10, dell-xps, windows-defender

I've updated Windows.

Every time blue screen appears I run the diagnosis that requires me to run the Windows Defender. And I can't access it through any method. Every time I click on any executable button to open Windows defender it's unresponsive, even if it's the MSASCui.EXE file.

Sticky Notes would show up on the Taskbar but never on screen. and even the taskbar button disappears on its own after a few minutes.

I have also attempted automatic disk repairs, no avail.

Do I have a hardware problem?

Comment: It could be a failing hard drive, back up important data to an external storage device now, then try a few things using command prompt and the built in Dell diagnostics. What specific model Dell is it?

Comment: It's a Dell XPS 12 ultrabook. How do you suggest I backup?

Comment: Copy and paste important files to an external hard drive or other storage device. There should be 4 numbers after XPS12 example, 9250, 9Q33 etc. Here is your diagnostics page, I would run the hard drive diagnostics after you back up files......http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln114988/dell-diagnostic-tools-to-diagnose-and-fix-hardware-problems-on-your-dell-pc-tablet-or-servers?lang=en

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It's Dell XPS 12 9Q23. And what I meant by my question was, whether I should back up my Windows, and should I back it up to an external hard drive or the old CD-ROM method everyone recommends?

Comment: I prefer a usb hard drive. CD's are unreliable in my opinion.